# How to restrict a field in SharePoint online lists?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, form

I would like to restrict a field value modification only for admins.

I did not find any option for that but in that case of there is no possibility is there any chance to create multiple forms for one SharePoint list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such options out of the box. Sharepoint doesn't have an field level security option.

What you can do:

1. Create Info-path form with 2 different views (but this is just smoke and mirrors)
2. You could potentially develop such functionality in POwerApps (but users could still navigate to list and edit in quick edit mode)
3. You could use the an lookup to another list as a field (the other list would be readable to everyone but editable only by the admins, but in that case admin would have to first enter the value from the other list and then edit the main one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer below in the link is from 2017 but may still apply - No out of the box feature, but look into 3rd party

[Link to Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/restrict-edit-access-to-certain-columns-in-a/b5b74be6-4301-4e34-ba97-9fa8b36edb9d)